# Match a number only when it is not part of a hex color code PHP

Tags: php, regex, colors

I'm trying to match numbers and replace them with `(matched number)px`

The thing is that I want to match them **ONLY** when they're **not** part of a hex color code. My input can contain hex color codes in two ways:
`#xxx` or `#xxxxxx` where the `x` can be a letter from `a-f` or a number from `0-9`.

The regex I currently have is this:

`$input = preg_replace('/(?<!#..)(\d)(?!px)/i', '$1px', $input);`

This works only with a 3 digit hex code and that too only when the digit is at the third place.

I want something applicable in all situations. This should replace only those numbers that are not part of a hex code and don't already have a `px` after them. Thanks!

EDIT: since negative lookbehind can't contain an indefinite number of characters (no quantifiers that is) I have no idea what to do.

The input and output should be like:

**input**: #da4 10
**output**: #da4 10px

**input**: #122222 10
**output**: #122222 10px

**input**: #4444dd 20px
**output**: #4444dd 20px

**input** 30 10 20 20 #414 20 99 #da4
**output**: 30px 10px 20px 20px #414 20px 99px #da4

Comment: Can you add a list of samples with what should and shouldn't match please?

Comment: Start with `(\d|[a-f])` for hex checking. `3`, or `6` characters long will be a bit more difficult.

Comment: i slightly change your regex - https://www.regex101.com/r/fP9gS1/1

Comment: @JorgeCampos I added that information :)

Comment: `\b(?<!#)(\d+)(?!px)\b`

Comment: @cmorrissey this regex is correct, it works, thank you! You can answer below if you want me to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(?<!#)\b(\d+)\b(?!px)` (replace with `$1px`).
[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/kX4kV3/1)

---

Explanation:

```
(?<!#)   make sure this isn't hex
\b       make sure we're matching the whole number, not just a part of it
(\d+)    capture the number
\b       again, make sure we've captured the whole number
(?!px)   make sure there's no px
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex:

```
\b(?<!#)\d+\b
# \b     Assert position at a word boundary 
# (?<!#) Negative Lookbehind
# \d+    Match a number with 1 to ilimited digits 
# \b     Assert position at a word boundary 

$input = '30 10 20 20 #414 20 99 #da4 #122222 10 #4444dd 20px';
$input = preg_replace('/\b(?<!#)\d+\b/', '$0px', $input);
print($input);
```

[Code example](http://ideone.com/7BXxMB)